# CSS - IOS Keyboard shifts whole document up

Tags: html, css, ios

I have a Text Messaging Mobile Site App that has the following divisions and CSS

```css
.messageDisplay {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.messageDisplayHeader {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 1px 4px;
}

.messageDisplayTextboxArea {
  height: 3.5em;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 16%) 0px -1px 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.messageTextbox {
  resize: none;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: calc(100% - 14%);
  background-color: #fef3f1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: #fc768a;
}
```

```html
<div class="messageDisplay" id="messageDisplay">
  <div class="messageDisplayHeader"></div>
  <div class="messageDisplayBody" id="messageDisplayBody">

  </div>
  <div class="messageDisplayTextboxArea" id="messageDisplayTextboxArea">
    <textarea id="messageTextbox" class="messageTextbox" maxlength="300" placeholder="Type a message"></textarea>
    <div class="messageSendBtn" id="messageSendBtn">
      <i data-feather="chevron-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When using an IOS Device to focus in on the `textarea` the whole page shifts up.
When the `textarea` is focused out, the page stays shifted upwards.

I tried to solve this by doing the following:

```js
var messageTextBoxEle = document.getElementById('messageTextbox');
  messageTextBoxEle.onfocus = function(){
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Right now it behaves as such

[image]

I also tried setting the page's `margin-bottom:0;` when the textarea is focused out but it doesnt seem to work.

Anyone have suggestions?